# Send multi request by axios, stop all request if first response 500 and redirect to login

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using axios 0.19.2, I send some requests to backend like this:

```
axios.get(API_PATH+'/request_a').then(res => res.data)
axios.get(API_PATH+'/request_b').then(res => res.data)
axios.get(API_PATH+'/request_c').then(res => res.data)
axios.get(API_PATH+'/request_d').then(res => res.data)
```

I try to make backend return 500 error code in the first request and I want to stop after requests.

```
window.axios = axios.create({
    validateStatus: (status) => {
        // console.log(status);
        return true;
    }
});
window.axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // console.log(response.data);
    return response;
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

I try to redirect with window.location in validateStatus, window.axios.interceptors.response.use where I can get response but browser spin unlimitted due to to many request are sent in the same time. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: You could try using RxJS and then do something like race between the requests

Comment: I think Promise.all() could help you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I think my problem is hard to archive so maybe there is no solution, I will using Promise.all